# String Format in Java

Tags: java, string, format

Assuming that i have the following string :

```
1 - <how_subject> "Please forgive me"
2 - <who> "Princess Peach"
3 - <what> "gave me a hickey."
```

How can I only print what is inside the quotes ? ( Please forgive me Princess Peach gave me a hickey.)

The text i want to print is "Please forgive me Princess Peach gave me a hickey." without the quotes.

Comment: You mean print "how_subject", "who", and "what", i.e. the things inside the brackets?

Comment: I want to print -> Please forgive me Princess Peach gave me a hickey.

Comment: You mean the text inside the quotes, not inside the brackets? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I wanted to say quotes, i will edit the question. The text i want to print is "Please forgive me Princess Peach gave me a hickey."

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this if you want to get the string inside brackets `<>`

```
String str = "1 - <how_subject> \"Please forgive me\"2 - <who> \"Princess Peach\"3 - <what> \"gave me a hickey.\"";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\<(.*?)\\>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/tcjEBN)

And if you want to get the string betwen the quotes `""` then simply change the regex pattern to:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/hZL4AW)

Comment: This it is : 1 - <how_subject> "Please forgive me" 2 - <who> "Princess Peach" 3 - <what> "gave me a hickey."

Comment: @CalinCretu:- You need to escape the double quotes inside your string and that is why I used the \

Answer (score 1):

You can either apply a regular expression or simply use `indexOf()` and `lastIndexOf()` to extract the quoted text:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
lines.add("1 - <how_subject> \"Please forgive me\"");
lines.add("2 - <who> \"Princess Peach\"");
lines.add("3 - <what> \"gave me a hickey.\"");

List<String> quotedText = new ArrayList<>();
for (String line: lines) {
   quotedText.add(line.substring(line.indexOf('"') + 1, line.lastIndexOf('"')));
}

System.out.print(String.join(" ", quotedText));
```

Or in case your input is a single String:

```
String input = "1 - <how_subject> \"Please forgive me\"\n2 - <who> \"Princess Peach\"\n3 - <what> \"gave me a hickey.\"";
String[] lines = input.split("\\n");

List<String> quotedText = new ArrayList<>();
for (String line: lines) {
   quotedText.add(line.substring(line.indexOf('"') + 1, line.lastIndexOf('"')));
}

System.out.print(String.join(" ", quotedText));
```

The code above will lead to this output:

```
Please forgive me Princess Peach gave me a hickey.
```

Comment: It is a good idea, but i my case i have only one string, not a list o strings, it is a string that was returned from a function.

Comment: @CalinCretu: You should be more precise in your question. You did not provide any code, so we can only guess how your input looks like. I added another block of code to my answer with a single String holding the input.